# Divergence and Stokes theorem, Annulus and Torus, Closed path

Tags: closed-form, line-integrals, divergence-theorem

The Divergence Theorem is generally defined as

\begin{align}
\int_\mathcal{V} (\nabla \cdot \vec F)\mathrm dV = \oint_{\mathcal{S}}( \vec F \cdot \vec n)\mathrm dS.
\end{align}

Moreover, the classical Stokes Theorem is generally defined as

\begin{align}
\int_\mathcal{S} (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \mathrm{d} \mathrm{S}  =  \oint_{\mathcal{L}} \vec{F} \cdot 
\mathrm{d}\mathrm{L}.
\end{align}

Here $\oint_{S}$, $\oint_{\mathcal{L}}$ are defined as boundary or closed surface/path integral. In the literature a closed surface/path is generally defined as **one closed** path/surface.

Considering a 2D [annulus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) shape, e.g., a circle with a hole, there is not only one closed path, rather we have **two closed** paths.

From a formal and mathematical point of view, is it reasonable to distinguish between those two differently closed integrals in a similar way of either writing $\int$ or $\oint$.

**Edit:**

From the discussion below we may summarize, that a distinction between both integrals does not always makes sense, e.g., Stokes theorem, however considering the Divergence theorem it might be reasonable.

Comment: My opinion is that we should always just write $\int_D$ where $D$ is our domain of integration (or k-chain, or whatever). If we want to integrate along the boundary of $D$, we should write $\int_{\partial D}$. This notation comes from the world of smooth manifolds and differential forms, which is to me the clearest way to understand integrating on interesting domains.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Thank you for your reply. Do you know some important mathematical laws, where it is worth making a distinction?

Comment: To my mind it is just notation, and it should never matter as long as adequate context is provided. It is important to note that the machinery of differential forms was (I believe) invented to deal with the problem of properly assigning signs (positive or negative) to integrals over boundaries of surfaces when the boundary is complicated as in your annulus example.

Comment: $\oint$ is completely redundant. It is only there to make some people “feel good”. An integral requires only two things: an integrand, and a domain of integration so $\int_{\text{domain of integration}}(\text{integrand})$ (there are other mild variants where rather than having a point-set domain like $D$ mentioned above, one writes a parametrized object, such as $\int_{\gamma}\omega$ where $\gamma$ is say a parametrized curve, but still, there’s only two things to specify). Anyway, if you know what your domain of integration is, you’ll know if it’s the boundary of something else.

Comment: Addendum to the above comment. I am apparently wrong about the history. It wasn't until later that people recognized the utility of differential forms in getting a handle on integrating boundaries. It would be better to say that handling boundaries is the crown jewel of the theory of integration of differential forms.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think it is not completely redundant. I find it quite reasonable to have different symbols for either closed surfaces or the whole boundary itself. For example, from the definition of the divergence theorem, it is not directly obvious.

Comment: @ConvexHull what you’re saying is exactly why I used the terms “redundant” and “feel good”. Meaning it does not convey any **extra** information that is not already contained in the precise statement of the theorem (hence redundant). Note, redundancy is not bad; it certainly doesn’t harm anyone (it could if people don’t know what the various symbols mean (but I don’t lump you in that group)). I was once in the $\oint$ camp, but it’s been about 4 years since I left, and with more exposure, you’ll be fine with dropping it too :)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. Last example. Let us also consider the classical Stokes theorem, generally defined as 

$$\iint_S (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{S}  =  \oint_{\mathcal{L}} \vec{F} \cdot 
\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}.$$

If no extra information is given: Does $\oint$ refer to a closed path or the whole boundary? In this case it is obviously different. Or isn't it?

Comment: Just write $\partial S$ and the meaning becomes unambiguous (once we take the correct orientations into account).

Comment: However, $\partial S$ would refer to the whole boundary, which is not the standard definition of the classical Stokes theorem. Of course, it might be possible, that such a geometrical situation might not be possible, meaning that a closed path must always be the full boundary, considering the Stokes theorem.

Comment: Stokes theorem literally says $\int_S(\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\cdot d\mathbf{A}=\int_{\partial S}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}$. And there’s another thing, we dont **need** to put two integral signs in front of $S$, one suffices and with the right definitions it conveys the same meaning. Stokes’ theorem makes no restrictions on the number of connected components of the boundary $\partial S$.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. The Stokes theorem can be stated in one sentence: "The line integral of a vector field over a (closed) loop is equal to the flux of its curl through the enclosed surface." The only situation, where I can find two loops of a enclosed surface is a Torus, cutted in two halfs. However, if one would apply Stokes theorem, the curl through the surface is useless, since there is a path through both circles which does not necessarily have to go through the surface, meaning, the distinction between closed path and whole boundary is meaningless for Stokes.

Comment: Note that, it is **not** meaningless for Gauss theorem.